# missing semicolon - jshint - syntax error?

Tags: javascript

Why does jshint.com say I'm missing a semi-colon here.  Do I need to add parentheses, is this a syntax stipulation?

```
function fill_id(a,b) {
    return document.getElementById( a ).innerHTML = b;
}
```

Comment: parentheses fixed the error..don't know why?

Comment: jshint doesn't like assignment in return statement. Another example: function test() { return a = 1; }

Comment: I don't like assignment in a return statement either. And looking at that particular function I don't see the point of returning the value that was passed in in parameter `b` anyway. I would think a more logical return from a `fill_id` function would be either a boolean to indicate whether the specified element was found, or a refence to that element if found and null if not. (Or just undefined in all cases.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*JSHint maintainer here.*

This has been fixed in our master branch. The website still uses the older (more stable) release, though.

Answer (score 3):

jsHint does not like the assignment on the return statement. If you remove the return the message goes away. The message is probably misleading.